# store json locally in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

how do i store json data locally without having to extract from a specific url eg. from, `www.example.com/myjson.php`

The situation:
My code works, but only when it is uploaded and run through a server

eg. `www.example.com/mycodethatworks.html`

But when i run it locally my json code wont return any value.

Thus when i build it with 'adobe build' my whole code is useless and doesn't work as the json are not returning any value.

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
// store the value in the localStorage
localStorage.setItem( "myJSON", JSON.stringify(myJSONvar) );

// read the value from the localStorage and parse it
myJSONvar = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("myJSON") );
```